# Selenium unable to get element cause by else-statement

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, instagram

That pursue of the issue : [Instagram have 2 type of xpath? How it could be remedied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215283/instagram-have-2-type-of-xpath-how-it-could-be-remedied/67257775#67215283) i don't solved my `else-statement` when is getting a "private profile"

it return me a error :

[image]

My code :

```
for follower in followers:
        #Iterate into the list
        browser.get(follower)
        sleep(2)
        
        if browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) a.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title"):
                print("Public profil")
                pass
              
        else:
            print("private profil")   
            pass
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

You could use `try... except` instead of `if... else`. In your case it could be:

```
for follower in followers:
        #Iterate into the list
        browser.get(follower)
        sleep(2)
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) a.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title"):
            print("Public profil")
        except:
            print("private profil") 
            continue
```

Comment: I know that, but the problem of `except` are is stop the looping after he arrive on private profile

Comment: why does it stop the loop? There is no `brake` in it so it shouldn't

Comment: i don't why, maybe he thinks it should stop after an `except `

Comment: i just edited and added `continue`. could you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your `if..else` clause with a `try/except` block with a `NoSuchElementException` within your loop.  This way if the element is not found in each loop it shouldn't crash

```
for follower in followers:
        #Iterate into the list
        browser.get(follower)
        sleep(2)
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li:nth-of-type(2) a.-nal3 span").get_attribute("title"):
        print("Public profil")                   
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("private profil")
```

If you want to stop the loop once a private profile is reached, just add a `break` after the 2nd `print()` statement

Package to add at top of script:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Still have same error for private profile
console return: 

Public profile
Private profile
7646
27
eligible
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Insta\Py-master.py", line 88, in <module>